# how to use redis and sequelize together

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, sequelize.js

im using redis for caching and sequelize as my orm.
i want to cache every query as key and it's result as value.
let me give you an example of how i'm trying to do it
imagine user request for all blogs that are created by himself, normally we would write something like this

```
blogs.findAll({where:{author:req.params.id}})
```

when i want to cache something like this i add an attribute named as model and for this example model would be equal to blog after that i will stringify this object and use it as key. this way i can easily create the key and check whether user response is cached or not, but i don't want to rewrite code for every request for checking redis and deciding to make query to database or not and i have 2 models now so i write this piece of code

```
for (m in models) {
        models[m].myFindAll = function (options = {}) {
            return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
                try {
                    const key = Object.assign({}, options);
                    key.model = m;
                    key.method = "findAll";
                    var result = await redis.get(JSON.stringify(key));
                    if (result) {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(result));
                    }
                    result = await models[m].findAll(options);
                    redis.set(JSON.stringify(key), JSON.stringify(result));
                    resolve(result);
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

as you can see i have an object that contains every model that i have and it is named models.
firstly i added User and after that i added Blog.
my problem is that when i try to use myFindAll function on User Model it won't work becuse it tries to set key.model with value of variable m which will be Blog in the run time, i solved it when i passed the model name an argument to my function but i don't want it that way and i think there should be a better way be i can't find it, isn't there some way of accessing right model through this object?

another thing that i tried to used libraries like sequelize-redis-cache and ... but i wanted to do it my way and i don't want to use this library